# Multiple Nibs in Xcode 4 Problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, xcode4, xib

I am having a problem in Xcode 4 where I have a tab bar controller and two nib files - one being the main window and the other being an other view - and when i try to make a tab view load from the other nib, Xcode 4 doesn't see the other nib. When the menu that should allow you to select a view comes down, nothing shows up...

**UPDATE: My wording is very confusing. in the atributes tap, the drop down menu "nib name" isn't getting populated with my nib files.**

HELP!

Picture: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/852/screenshot20110513at224.png/

Comment: Post your code. It's hard to guess what's wrong without seeing some code.

Comment: A few more details on exactly how you have this set up would help.  Code too...

Comment: I don't think its a problem with the code. Xcode 4 is just not seeing my nib files when i try to tell a view to load from an other nib...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is broken in XCode 4 (now at 4.02). The dropdown will not populate, **even if the nib in question is added to the relevant target.** It is very likely that somebody at Apple forgot to make a connection inside a NIB somewhere, so IB is calling methods on a nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing in the nib name without the .xib.

For example if your nib is called DetailViewController.xib, type in DetailViewController.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried just typing the name of the Nib file into that field?

Comment: yes I have tried doing that... when I run it, it gives me a SIGABRT error. When I take that away there's no error... is it just me or are other people experiencing this?

Comment: Have you made sure that the nib file was added to your target? Select the build settings for your project, you should see a list of resources to copy, make sure the nib is in there.

Comment: yes everything is in there. Is this happening to anybody else?

Comment: Can you post a picture of what the nib you are attempting to load looks like?

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard. even if the nib is just a blank view it still doesn't show up. there is a picture of it in the main post

Comment: @kubi, this is a question, not an answer. You might want to consider deleting it. On the other hand, if you take out XCode 4 and make a project with two nibs and try it, you might solve the problem for the entire world ;)